# AspectJ parent method

Tags: android, aspectj

I have a around method which tries to hide keyboard on `dispatchTouchEvent` method.

```
@Around("execution(boolean (@com.savaskoc.keyboard.KeyboardHide *).dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))")
```

This works well if I override `dispatchTouchEvent` method from `android.app.Activity` like that

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Is there any way for intercept parent class' method?

Ps: I tried change "execution" to "call" and it gives;

```
[warning] advice defined in com.savaskoc.keyboard.KeyboardAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch
```

I have annotated class named `BaseActivity`. Around works when I override `dispatchTouchEvent` like this

```
@KeyboardHide
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ToolbarActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

but when I remove this method, I'm getting a warning like above

Answer (score 0):

Either you intercept calls instead of executions like this:

```java
call(boolean (@com.savaskoc.keyboard.KeyboardHide *).dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))
```

Or, if this is not good enough because calls are being made from code outside the control of your AspectJ compiler, you can continue using execution pointcuts but need to weave aspects into the third party library you want to intercept via binary weaving, creating a new, woven version of it.

**Update after *Hyperion*'s edit:**

The warning `advice ... has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]` simply means that the AspectJ compiler has not found any joinpoints to weave your pointcut into. In this case it means just what I mentioned above when I said:

> calls are being made from code outside the control of your AspectJ compiler

This means (repeating myself in other words) that either you have to weave your aspect code into the original JAR containing class `ToolbarActivity` via binary compile-time weaving or via load-time weaving during runtime, making sure that the aspect weaver is loaded before the original JAR so it can intercept it during class-loading. I have no idea if LTW (or Java agents in general) is available on Android JVMs (I would guess no) because I have never used Android in my whole life, but these two are the options you have. The workaround to override methods you want to intercept always works if all else fails.