# How to use @Before on Activity onPause without overriding method

Tags: aop, aspectj

```
@Before("execution(*  android.app.Activity.onPause(..))")
public void postOnPause(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) thisJoinPoint.getTarget();
    Log.d("TEST", "YAY Activity paused");
}
```

This works out great if I in my MainActivity override:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Is there any way I could solve this without adding the override? Because the superclass Activity should still have that method defined and should be run even tho the subclass has not implemented it.

Is this possible?

Comment: One workaround is to have a `BaseActivity` to override `onPause`. Otherwise, it seems you have to do runtime weaving. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34843989/620138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not an Android developer, my answer will explain basic AspectJ mechanisms.*

As *Aaron He* already said when pointing you to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840802/aspectj-parent-method/34843989#34843989), you either need to instrument the upstream JAR containing the base class during runtime via LTW (load-time weaving) or weave it during compile time via binary weaving.

If it was your own code calling `onPause`, you could just use a `call()` pointcut instead of `execution()`, but probably the framework issues the calls, making this option a bad choice.